# Webpack Angular 2 bundle whole project in single file

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am trying to bundle whole my Angular 2 project in one single index.html file (js, fonts, css and images).

Below is my current webpack config file, what should I do or update here to bundle all in one file, (with map file) if it is possible ?

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {

        entry: './app/main.ts',
        output : {
            path: './dist',
            filename: 'app.bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            preLoaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loader: 'tslint'
                }
            ],
            loaders : [
                { 
                    test: /\.ts$/, 
                    loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(html)$/, 
                    loader: 'raw-loader'
                },           
                {
                    test: /.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|eot|ttf|svg|cur|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
                    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'url-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './index.html'
            }),
        ]
    };
```

Comment: Just wondering, why would you need to do this?

Comment: I am working with Dynamic CRM web resource. Usually we have some smaller projects which tend to be complicated. I want to reduce number of files if projects are simple.
If they become complicated maybe I will bundle them in separate files.